# find regex match on pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark datafrme like below

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |strval                                                                         |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"position":"left","title":"journeys","link":"https://www.abcd.com","rank":549}|
|2  |{"position":"left","title":"journeys","link":"https://www.abcd.com","rank":5}  |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to find only the value of rank using the regexp
I have tried below code

```
select id,
regexp_extract("strval", '(\"rank\":)(\d+)',2) as rn
from tbl
```

but all I am getting is empty values.
Can someone please guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using regex here, and instead should *parse* your JSON content to extract the `rank` key.  Assuming you are using PySpark 1.6+, we can try:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

df = df.withColumn("rank", get_json_object(df.strval, f'$.rank'))
```

Assuming you want to continue solving this via Spark SQL, you were already on the right track.  I would suggest *not* putting the column name in double quotes, as that might be mistaken for a string literal.  Also, you only need to use one capture group, for the numerical rank:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(strval, '"rank":(\d+)', 1) AS rn
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: I need it in spark sql format.get_json_object I have already tried like this 'get_json_object("strval", 'strval.rank') as rn1' but getting null values

Comment: ...well that's not what my answer is suggesting you try

Comment: it's working fine for dataframe.Can you please suggest anything similar in spark sql?